# Announce text using AVSpeechSynthesizer after VoiceOver stops speaking text

Tags: ios, voiceover, uiaccessibility, avspeechsynthesizer

I need to announce some text to all users of my application when they perform some action. To do so I use `AVSpeechSynthesizer`. This works well, unless you use VoiceOver to perform the action. Because VoiceOver is announcing some system provided information to the user, then my `AVSpeechUtterance` is played at the same time, so the voices overlap. How can I queue up my speech utterance so that it isn't played until after VoiceOver finishes speaking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by observing VoiceOver activities. First add a Voiceover notification observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(voiceOverDidStop:) name:UIAccessibilityAnnouncementDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

Then, in the specified method:

```
-(void)voiceOverDidStop:(NSNotification*)n {
    NSString* msg;
    NSNumber* finished;

    msg = [[n userInfo] objectForKey:UIAccessibilityAnnouncementKeyStringValue];
    finished = [[n userInfo] objectForKey:UIAccessibilityAnnouncementKeyWasSuccessful];

    if(finished) {
        // send the AVSpeechSynthsizer message
    }
}
```

Remember to remove the observe before disposing your app!

Another method you can use (if applicable) is to edit the `accessibilityLabel` and `accessibilityHint` properties of the object the user is acting with. Set those properties to `@""` so VoiceOver knows there is nothing to say about that object.

Hope this helps you even if my answer came quite late :
)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether VoiceOver is running and post an `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification` with your message instead of using `AVSpeechSynthesizer`.

Comment: That's not going to work in this case, as I need to control the utterance pitch and rate for this announcement.

Comment: In that case, I don't believe any existing API supports your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with `asyncAfter`, the code is SwiftUI but I hope you get the idea:

```swift
Button {
    if !UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning {
        readOutLoud(translation)
    }
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "speaker.wave.3.fill")
}
.accessibilityElement()
.accessibilityLabel("Listen")
.accessibilityAction {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
        readOutLoud(translation)
    })
}
```

The button reads a text when is pressed and VoiceOver is not active.

When VoiceOver is activated, the text will be read through the `accessibilityAction` with the desired delay.